# jQuery 2.1 “Syntax error, unrecognized expression” error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error in a asp file where I am dynamically building a data sting for use in an ajax call.

The error occurs on the input TitleName  and is the error message is

```
Syntax error, Unrecognised expression: BankingUser%201
```

When I capture the title with no spaces there is no error, this error only appears when there are spaces in my input

The title is added to my data string as follows

```
TitleName = $( "#txtTitleName" );
TitleName = ConvertData(TitleName);  // Reformat Input String
DataString_position = DataString_position + ""&TitleName="" + TitleName  ;
```

Comment: ``DataString_position = DataString_position + "&TitleName=" + TitleName  ;``

Comment: Was has this to do with a [tag:asp-classic]? It maybe this code is running in a Classic ASP site but this is client side code, so tagging this [tag:asp-classic] is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataString_position = DataString_position + ""&TitleName="" + TitleName  ;
// Here -------------------------------------^-----------^
```

I think you just want to remove those:

```
DataString_position = DataString_position + "&TitleName=" + TitleName  ;
```

But if you want actual double quote chars there for some reason, use single quotes around the overall string:

```
DataString_position = DataString_position + '"&TitleName="' + TitleName  ;
```

...or escape with a backslash (`\`):

```
DataString_position = DataString_position + "\"&TitleName=\"" + TitleName  ;
```

---

Side note: As you're building something to put in a query string, you want to URI-encode it. Instead of

```
+ TitleName ;
```

at the end, use

```
+ encodeURIComponent(TitleName) ;
```

...to make sure characters are correctly URI-encoded.

Comment: I'm not sure they need either. Looks to me like they are trying to build a URL querystring so it should be `DataString_position = DataString_position + "&TitleName=" + TitleName;` like @EhsanSajjad suggested in his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605474/jquery-2-1-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-error#comment36236018_23605474).

Comment: @Lankymart: Right. My first sentence after the opening code block is "I think you just want to remove those." I guess I could highlight that more... *Edit* Just did.